# Convert java code to c# code

Tags: c#

I am reading the "Head First Object Oriented Design and Analysis" and I am stuck on page 254.

In the java code below, I am trying to convert the "Matches" method to a c# one.

```
public class InstrumentSpec {

  private Map properties;

  public InstrumentSpec(Map properties) {
    if (properties == null) {
      this.properties = new HashMap();
    } else {
      this.properties = new HashMap(properties);
    }
  }

  public Object getProperty(String propertyName) {
    return properties.get(propertyName);
  }

  public Map getProperties() {
    return properties;
  }

  public boolean matches(InstrumentSpec otherSpec) {
    for (Iterator i = otherSpec.getProperties().keySet().iterator(); 
         i.hasNext(); ) {
      String propertyName = (String)i.next();
      if (!properties.get(propertyName).equals(
           otherSpec.getProperty(propertyName))) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is the C# code that I have so far:

```
public class InstrumentSpec
{
    private IDictionary _properties;

    public InstrumentSpec(IDictionary properties)
    {
        this._properties = properties == null ? new Hashtable() : new Hashtable(properties);
    }

    public object GetProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        return _properties.Contains(propertyName);
    }

    public IDictionary Properties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
        set { _properties = value; }
    }

    public virtual bool Matches(InstrumentSpec otherSpec)
    {
        foreach (var prop in otherSpec.Properties)
        {
            if (!prop.Equals(otherSpec.Properties))
            {
                return false;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Anyone has got any idea how to make the Matching method work so that it checks if two objects match?

Comment: isnt there an .equals() for every object?

Comment: yes there is an equals() method on every object and as you can see I have used it in my code but I can't seem to get it right with IDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your comparison:

```
if (!prop.Equals(otherSpec.Properties))
```

When do you expect any single "property" to equal the collection of "properties" which contains it?  The Java code is making comparisons with the object's internal collection of "properties":

```
if (!properties.get(propertyName).equals(
       otherSpec.getProperty(propertyName)))
```

Which basically means it's looping through a collection of "properties" and for each "property" in that collection it is comparing it with a similarly named "property" in another collection.  But you don't make any reference to the object's collection here:

```
private IDictionary _properties;
```

You need to compare the values from one collection to the values in the other collection.  Without doing any checking if the values actually *exist* in the collection (which I recommend doing), it might look something like this:

```
foreach (var prop in otherSpec.Properties.Keys)
{
    if (!otherSpec.Properties[prop].Equals(_properties[prop]))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java code iterates over the dictionary keys and compares the respective property values. You're currently iterating over the key/value pairs and compare them to the dictionary.

I guess something like

```
foreach (var key in otherSpec.Properties.Keys)
{
  if (!Properties[key].Equals(otherSpec.Properties[key]))
  {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

would be a better translation.

Answer (score 1):

You could completely copy the algorithm, if thats what you want:

```
public virtual bool Matches(InstrumentSpec otherSpec)
{
    foreach (var prop in otherSpec.Properties.Keys)
    {
        if (!Object.equals(properties[prop], otherSpec[prop]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But i would advise, to use generics, to know, which types we are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var keysEqual= Properties.Keys.SequenceEqual(otherSpec.Properties.Keys);
    var valuesEqual = Properties.Values.SequenceEqual(otherSpec.Properties.Values);

if(keysEqual && valueEqual)
{
//objects have the same properties and values
}
```